# add vertices to graph

Tags: r, addition, igraph, vertex

I want to add vertices to a graph object, but it doesn't work.

```
g = graph.ring(5)
subG = induced.subgraph(g, c(1,2,3)) ##extract sub-graph
v = V(g)[4] ##add vertex '4' to the sub-graph. 
result = subG + v
```

The result I expected will be a graph with vertices 1,2,3 and 4. With 4 unlinked to 1,2,3. But the output is IGRAPH U--- 7 2 -- Ring graph
It seems to have added 4 vertices to subG.

What's the reason for this and how to achieve my goal?

Comment: `Error in induced.subgraph(g, 1, 2, 3) : unused argument (3)`

Comment: @GaborCsardi it should be  subG = induced.subgraph(g, c(1,2,3)), which means to extract the subgraph formed by vertices 1,2,3

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `add.vertices` command:

```
g <- graph.ring(5)
subG <- induced.subgraph(g, c(1, 2, 3))
subG <- add.vertices(subG, 1)
```

This gives us

```
> subG
IGRAPH U--- 4 2 -- Ring graph
+ attr: name (g/c), mutual (g/l), circular (g/l)

> get.adjacency(subG)
4 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

[1,] . 1 . .
[2,] 1 . 1 .
[3,] . 1 . .
[4,] . . . .
```

Comment: Sorry I missed one code line. I do not want to just add a vertex, but to add some specific vertex, for example to add some nodes from the big graph to a subgraph, while keep all the attributes of the nodes.

Comment: Your code evaluates to `subG + 4`, which adds four vertices to `subG`; instead you want `subG + 1`.

Comment: But v=V(g)[4], which is a vertex object, instead of an integer

Comment: You cannot add vertex objects from one graph into another (because there is no such thing as a "vertex object" in igraph -- you only have a sequence of vertex IDs). You have to add a vertex manually to your new graph and then copy its attributes over.